# "Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction" when I run truffle test

Tags: truffle, testing, testrpc, truffle-test, unittesting

I'm running my unit test with truffle in ganache environment.
Here's my Lottery SC:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "./Token.sol";



library Random {
    /*
     * @dev startingValue is inclusive, endingValue is inclusive
     * naive implementation! Do not use in production
     * ie if 1, 10, rand int can include 1-10
     */
    function naiveRandInt(uint256 _startingValue, uint256 _endingValue)
        internal
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        // hash of the given block when blocknumber is one of the 256 most recent blocks; otherwise returns zero
        // create random value from block number; use previous block number just to make sure we aren't on 0
        uint randomInt = uint(blockhash(block.number - 1));
        // convert this into a number within range
        uint range = _endingValue - _startingValue + 1; // add 1 to ensure it is inclusive within endingValue

        randomInt = randomInt % range; // modulus ensures value is within range
        randomInt += _startingValue; // now shift by startingValue to ensure it is >= startingValue

        return randomInt;
    }
}

contract Lottery {
    IERC20 public erc20;
    uint256 public startTimestamp;
    uint256 public endTimestamp;
    uint256 public ticketCost;
    uint256 public ticketCounter;
    uint256 public winnerTicket;
    uint256 private prize;
    bool internal winnerWasChosen;
    address public _winner;
    

    mapping(address => bool) s_players;
    mapping(uint256 => address) s_ticket;
    mapping(address => uint256) public _balances;


    constructor(uint256 _startTimestamp, uint256 _endTimestamp, uint256 _ticketCost, IERC20 _token) {
        startTimestamp = _startTimestamp;
        endTimestamp = _endTimestamp;
        ticketCost = _ticketCost;
        erc20 = IERC20(_token);
    }

    function buyTicket() public returns (uint256 ticketId)  {
        require(erc20.balanceOf(msg.sender) > ticketCost, "not enough balance");
        require(block.timestamp >= startTimestamp, "Lottery is not started yet");
        require(block.timestamp < endTimestamp, "Lottery is over");
        require(!s_players[msg.sender], "Already got one ticket");
        
        erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), ticketCost);
        ticketCounter++;
        s_players[msg.sender] = true;
        s_ticket[ticketCounter] = msg.sender;
                               
        return ticketCounter;
    }

    function chooseWinner() public returns (address winner ) {
        require(block.timestamp >= endTimestamp, "Lottery isn't over");
        require(ticketCounter >= 1, "no tickets are sold");
        

        winnerTicket = Random.naiveRandInt(1, ticketCounter);
        _winner = s_ticket[winnerTicket];
        prize = ticketCost * ticketCounter;

        erc20.transfer(_winner, prize); 

        return (_winner );
        
    }

    function verifyStartLottery() public view returns (bool) {
        return (block.timestamp >= startTimestamp); 
    }

   function  verifyEndLottery() public view returns (bool) {
       return (block.timestamp >= endTimestamp);  
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint) {
        return ticketCost;  
    }

    function getTimestamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _addr) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[_addr];
    }
    
    function getPrize() public view returns (uint256){ 
        return ticketCost * ticketCounter;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_ticket[index];
    }

}
```

and here's my test:

```
const { expect, assert } = require('chai');
const Lottery = artifacts.require('Lottery');
const Token = artifacts.require('Token');

let token;
let lottery;
let verifyStartLottery;
let test, startTimestamp, endTimestamp;
let acc1bal, acc2bal, acc3bal;
let ticketCost;
let acc2balAfterRevert;


contract('Lottery', (accounts) => {

    
    before(async () => {
        token = await Token.deployed();
        lottery = await Lottery.deployed();
        

        
        startTimestamp = (await lottery.startTimestamp());
        endTimestamp = (await lottery.endTimestamp());
       
      })

    

    describe('When SC is deployed', () => {
        


        it('Should revert if account[2] calls buyTicket but lottery is not started', async () => {
            
            ticketCost = await lottery.getEntranceFee();
            await token.transfer(accounts[2], (ticketCost * 2), {from : accounts[0]});
            await token.approve( lottery.address, (ticketCost),  {from : accounts[2]});
            
            await lottery.buyTicket({from : accounts[2]});
            await expectRevert(lottery.buyTicket({from : accounts[2]}),"lottery is not started");
            
        })
```

This is the error I get:

````
1) Should revert if account[2] calls buyTicket but lottery is not started

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    IERC20.Transfer(
      from: <indexed> 0xC77504f40938cbd13A7a0fD705E4dD1eAf9BBB97 (type: address),
      to: <indexed> 0xdb95c705FEeF3ddDeD4498bd5A6F9569131D5874 (type: address),
      value: 10 (type: uint256)
    )

    IERC20.Approval(
      owner: <indexed> 0xdb95c705FEeF3ddDeD4498bd5A6F9569131D5874 (type: address),
      spender: <indexed> 0x58fa0b350B76e07F8BfD1027c1bd4B1BaC97f0c4 (type: address),
      value: 5 (type: uint256)
    )


    --------------------------- 

1) Contract: Lottery
       When SC is deployed
         Should revert if account[2] calls buyTicket but lottery is not started:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Lottery is not started ye
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Lottery.test.js:58:38)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)```
(test\Lottery.test.js:58:38) is this line: "await lottery.buyTicket({from : accounts[2]});"
````

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that the line `await lottery.buyTicket({from : accounts[2]});` reverts with the message "Lottery is not started yet".

You should either:

- Start the lottery (although, going by your test name I do not think this is what you want)
- Remove the line that buys a ticket where you do **not** catch the revert.

For the second solution, simply remove the line:

```js
await lottery.buyTicket({from : accounts[2]});
```

and keep the line:

```js
await expectRevert(lottery.buyTicket({from : accounts[2]}),"lottery is not started");
```

Comment: I've already tried to remove that line but I get this error:
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
      at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\Federico\node_modules\web3-providers-http\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:43:16)
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Federico\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:95:32)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Federico\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Federico\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-h
@onbjerg